# Refresh List<> Binding Spinner MVVM Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, mvvm, xamarin.forms

I am using a spinner which your itemSource is binding = PractiListEX

when you start the viewmodel.cs

```
 this._practiListEX = this.GetPracti().OrderBy(t => t.numsec).ToList();
 this.PractiListEX = this._practiListEX;
```

Where GetPracti is a list designed with query, the list changes when entering data.

```
   private List<PLABEN> GetPracti()
        {
         var Practic = new List<PLABEN>()
                 {
                    new PLABEN(){ValueD = "Seleccione Practica"}

                 };
...

return Practic;
```

El contructor :

```
 private List<PLABEN> _practiListEX;

 public List<PLABEN> PractiListEX
        {
            get { return _practiListEX; }
            set
            {
                 if (_practiListEX != value)
                 {

                _practiListEX = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged();
                }
            }
        }
```

Then I execute a button which executes these lines again, but the spinner list does not change

```
 this._practiListEX = this.GetPracti().OrderBy(t => t.numsec).ToList();
 this.PractiListEX = this._practiListEX;
```

- the other bingin used as entry or label work without problem.
  Thank you in advance for sharing your knowledge.

Comment: ,Can you share your contentpage xaml here? Because I don't find Spinner control in Xamarin.forms, what library do you use?

Answer (score 2):

Since the list will be changing, I'd change your bound property to be an `ObservableCollection`. Note that you wouldn't have to use `OnPropertyChanged` on this, because you'll only be changing the contents of the collection (not the property itself).

Whenever you want to update it with new data, just `Clear()` then add to it.

```
public ObservableCollection<PLABEN> PractiListEX { get; private set; }


PractiListEX.Clear();
foreach (var data in this.GetPracti().OrderBy(t => t.numsec).ToList())
{
    PractiListEX.Add(data);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much @d.moncada. We make the changes, but there are no updates yet. he noticed that when the view was started, the set was executed and get, but when updating, it did not execute set.

Comment: set only gets called if you change the property reference. In the situation I described above, you are only creating the ObservableCollection once (which will only call Set once). From there, you simply Clear or Add to it